# zk framework: message 'unknown message code:<code>' instead of standart labels

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat8, zk

I'm using ZK 8.0.1 and Tomcat 8.0.30.

I have several applications which are deployed to Tomcat. I put all zk jars to `$CATALINA_BASE/lib` because I want use one version of zk for all my applications.

My applications start and work fine except one thing. After some time of work I noticed that instead of all standard labels (e.g. label of buttons like 'yes', 'no') I see message in format *Unknown message code : *code**. It happens in all zk applications. Right after start of server all labels is displayed correctly.

I detected a moment when I think it starts:

1. open page of one application and click a button.
2. event handler throws unhandled runtime exception.
3. standard error dialog is showed but there is button with text *Unknown message code:27112200* instead of *OK*.

After executing steps above all standard labels in all applications isn't displayed correctly.

A cause this problem is exception:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resources may not be accessed if they are not currently started`.

StackTrace:

```
org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.validate(StandardRoot.java:245),
org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:212),
org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:206),
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getResource(ApplicationContext.java:554),
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getResource(ApplicationContextFacade.java:199),
org.zkoss.web.util.resource.ServletLabelLocator.locate0(ServletLabelLocator.java:90),
org.zkoss.web.util.resource.ServletLabelLocator.locate(ServletLabelLocator.java:75),
org.zkoss.util.resource.impl.LabelLoaderImpl.loadLabels(LabelLoaderImpl.java:260),
org.zkoss.util.resource.impl.LabelLoaderImpl.getLabel(LabelLoaderImpl.java:118),
org.zkoss.util.resource.impl.LabelLoaderImpl.getLabel(LabelLoaderImpl.java:109),
org.zkoss.util.resource.Labels.getLabel(Labels.java:61),
org.zkoss.mesg.Messages.getFromBundle(Messages.java:81),
org.zkoss.mesg.Messages.getNotFound(Messages.java:105),
org.zkoss.mesg.Messages.get(Messages.java:157),
org.zkoss.mesg.Messages.get(Messages.java:52)....
```

Maybe somebody knows how to resolve this problem and what I do wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Might be related:

I faced 'Unknown message code' errors on zk-oss as well. These appear when the framework tries to find localized labels for standard dialog buttons such as OK, CANCEL, YES, NO, etc. but fails to locate appropriate resources.

On debian the following solved it for me:

1. dpkg-reconfigure locales (then installing 'en_US.UTF-8')
2. restart of servlet-container